# How to keep mode-line in title bar even in new poped up frames?

Tags: org-mode, frames

I am using the following code to keep the org-pomodoro clock in the title bar,

```
(setq frame-title-format '("" invocation-name "@" system-name " " org-pomodoro-mode-line))
```

It works most of the time but whenever I start using org-note or anything else which pops up a new frame, the title bar changes to a new name and the org-pomodoro clock disappears.

How can I keep the org-pomodoro clock all the time in my title bar even in new poped up frames?

I had a similar issue with scroll-bar. It was set to be zero (disabled) but whenever a new frame was opened the scroll-bar reappeard again. I solved that issue by the following code,

```
(defun my/disable-scroll-bars (frame)
(modify-frame-parameters frame
                       '((vertical-scroll-bars . nil)
                         (horizontal-scroll-bars . nil))))
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'my/disable-scroll-bars)
```

Hoenstly, I don't know how to use the second code to solve my intiail problem.

Comment: Variable `org-pomodoro-mode-line` has to be defined for it to have an effect. Is it defined in the cases where you don't see its effect?

Comment: May I ask you to be more specific about where should I put the `org-pomodoro-mode-line` in defined function?

Comment: Dunno. I was just suggesting that when `frame-title-format` is used that variable will be interpreted. And if the variable isn't defined at that point then...